# how to read stanza message of xmpp in nodejs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, xmpp

i wan to send message using xmpp+nodejs

For this i send like this ..

```
 var mess_set = {
            "messageId": 1,
            "isHTML": false,
            "serverMsgts": 1482308138,
            "msgts": 1482308138,
            "rid": send_id,
            "sname": "Sender me..",
            "text": text,
            "sid": me_chat_id,
            "type": "0",
            "rname": "Developer recive..",
            "imgName": "64A419D8BAF811E6BFD706E21CB7534C---1480948613315cropped_image.jpg",
            "class": 'text-area'
        }
        var stanza = new xmpp.Element('message', {to: send_id + '@testing.twodegrees.io', type: 'chat', id: send_id}).
                c('body').t(mess_set)
        connection.send(stanza);
        var test = {'text': text, "class": 'text-area'}
```

this message sent and on the reciver side i got this message in this format

```
        Incoming_message..: <message to="586f2fc0ba5d09594e0ef5bf@testing.twodegrees.io" type="chat" id="586f2fc0
ba5d09594e0ef5bf" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" from="586f3b52ba5d09594b4d6e22@testing.
twodegrees.io/74ab3f34a0d5a2885768d29426c39ef6" xmlns="jabber:client"><body>[object Object]</body></messa
ge>
```

So when i try to get text message and all other detail that is sent from sender 
Using this code

```
  var body = stanza.getChild('body');
        var message = body.getText();

        var body = stanza.getChild('body');
```

this give me [objec objet]

I get this through

So My question is :
1-How i get original message with all other detail like image,id etc
Thanks